# Short film where an alien crew is transporting a ship full of criminals that accidentally get released

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-film

I have been looking for years for a short film. I think it was called Asylum. It was about an alien crew (one was kind of amphibian looking in a space suit, and the other was a crustacean like bug creature) transporting a ship full of criminals that accidentally get released. It was made in the early 2000s, I think, and I remember one line from the film, "Who puts the drink dispensing unit next to the prisoner release mechanism."

I have been looking form this short film for years since I saw it as a child. Could you please help me find it?
Thank you very much for your help.